# Sharepoint 2016 Search result issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

Sharepoint search results show files that user has with no permission

I am working on Sharepoint 2016. I have a requirement that when a user has no permission to a file, he/she  can not see file and file path in search result

regards,

Baban Ali

Answer (score 0):

I would check that your search crawl account has correct permissions on it. It should only have Full Read.

Here are some interesting blog posts and helpful articles to help you configure your search service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/create-and-configure-a-search-service-application 
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/10/19/how-to-properly-set-permissions-on-your-search-crawl-account-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Users who don't have access to the item should not see it in the search results - this is default behaviour. If they do, there is a configuration problem.

Hope this helps!